# How to use Gnuplot to print 3D plots (splot) with error bars and different linespoints

Tags: gnuplot

using `Gnuplot` to plot 3D charts with `splot` and errors with `zerror` does not allow us to have different lines with points. [Here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.2/zerror.html) are examples. I would like to use `splot` with error bars and still differentiate lines by different points. Like it is mentioned [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node328.html):

> The operation of with is also the same as in plot, except that the
> plotting styles available to splot are limited to lines, points,
> linespoints, dots, and impulses; the error-bar capabilities of plot
> are not available for splot.

Is there another solution for this problem in `Gnuplot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, there doesn't seem to be a direct plotting style for drawing error bars in 3D. It is possible to manipulate the input data to pseudo-draw the error bars with lines style.

Sample Script:

```
$inputdata <<EOD
# x y z zlow zhigh
1 1 1 0 2
2 1 2 1 3
3 1 3 2 4
4 1 4 3 5
5 1 5 4 6


1 2 5 1 7
2 2 4 1 7
3 2 3 1 7
4 2 2 1 7
5 2 1 1 7


1 3 3 1 4
2 3 3 2 5
3 3 3 3 6
4 3 3 2 5
5 3 3 1 4
EOD

# construct errorbar's line segments data
set table $first
plot $inputdata using 1:2:4:($1-0.1):4:5:0 with table
set table $second
plot $inputdata using 1:2:5:($1+0.1):4:5:0 with table
unset table

# summarize data into data block $errbars
stats $inputdata using 0 nooutput
set print $errbars 
do for [i=1:STATS_records] {
  print $first[i]
  print $second[i]
  print ""
  print ""
}
set print

set xrange [0:6]
set yrange [0:4]

set key noautotitle

splot $inputdata using 1:2:3:2 with linespoints pt 7 lc variable, \
      $errbars   using 1:2:3:2 with lines lc variable, \
      $errbars   using 4:2:5:2 with lines lc variable, \
      $errbars   using 4:2:6:2 with lines lc variable

pause -1
```

It uses the line-wise data (x,y,z,zlow,zhigh) of the data points and error range as inputs to build the data to draw the error bars and whiskers. Once that's done, we can draw each part of the error bar in lines style.

Result:

[image]

---

Here's another solution using vector style which is actually much simpler than above script.

Sample script:

```
$inputdata <<EOD
# x y z zlow zhigh
1 1 1 0 2
2 1 2 1 3
3 1 3 2 4
4 1 4 3 5
5 1 5 4 6


1 2 5 1 7
2 2 4 1 7
3 2 3 1 7
4 2 2 1 7
5 2 1 1 7


1 3 3 1 4
2 3 3 2 5
3 3 3 3 6
4 3 3 2 5
5 3 3 1 4
EOD

set xrange [0:6]
set yrange [0:4]

unset key
set style arrow 3 heads size 0.05,90 lc variable

splot $inputdata using 1:2:3:2 with linespoints pt 7 lc variable, \
      $inputdata using 1:2:4:(0):(0):($5-$4):2 with vectors arrowstyle 3 

pause -1
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are right. It doesnt look very clear. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I added another solution using vector style which is much simpler.